# Imported Links don't work (AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Can anyone help me fixing my issue?
How can I make my links work, which come by ajax?

I tried to write some links directly into the document and they worked pretty well, but the "imported" ones don't.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdbhB/)

-> res/ajax/search.php

```
    <?php

$search = $_POST['search'];

if( $search != "" ) {

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('invoice');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM profile";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    for( $a=1; $a <= $rows; $a++ ) {

        $query =  "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE full_name LIKE '%$search%' AND id='$a'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if($array != "") {

            echo "<a href='#' class='address'>" . $array['full_name'] . "</a><br />";

        }

    }

}


echo "<a href='#' class='address'>currywurst</a><br />";
echo "<a href='#' class='address'>bratwurst</a><br />";

?>
```

Comment: The links just go to `#`, so what behaviour are you expecting them to have?

Comment: there is no href link...

Comment: "Imported Links don't work" For sure they work as expected. Maybe you just don't know what to expect

Comment: i haven't written the code yet, but every class "address" should open an alert with "suprise" or something else, just to know it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.address', function(){
  alert('something');
});
```

Instead of:

```
$('.address').click(function(){
  alert('something');
});
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thanks! but where is the exact differences between this methods?

Comment: when you declare a simple click (as you did), you are binding the event only at the current DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should try binding handlers to ajax loaded content in your ajax callback. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[name="search"]').keyup(function(){

        $.post('res/ajax/search.php',
        {
            search: $('input[name="search"]').val()
        },
        function(data) {
            $('#search-preview').html(data);

            // onclick moved to ajax callback function
            $('.address').click(function(){

                alert('something');

            });

        });

    });

});
```